# Dropdowns affects other dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html

So I found this piece of code online to make dropdowns based on  instead of , to be able to style it easier.

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.wrapper-dropdown').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

The things is I want to have three different dropdowns based on this and thought I could just go like:

```
var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
var dd2 = new DropDown( $('#dd2') );
var dd3 = new DropDown( $('#dd3') );
```

Well, when I select something in #dd2 or #dd3 it also affects #dd.

Comment: On a side note, you can always use something like [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to style your selects.

Comment: I'm switching right away, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to me like the .dropdown class to all ul's is causing the problem. try modifying this to set different classes and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a naming conflict between your code, and google maps code. Changing the name of the class from `dropdown` to anything else (like `selectpicker`) should fix the problem.